# Problems implementing a recursive find extension method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, recursion

I am attempting to implement a recursive extension method in VB.net that will find all objects with a certain property set so I can call it like so...

```
Dim camp As New CampaignStructure 'Populated with a full structure of course
Dim lstFoundItems As List(Of CategoryStructure) = camp.Categories.FindRecursive((Function(c) c.Found = False), 3)
```

My VB.Net classess and modules currently look like this

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace MyStructure
Public Class CategoryStructure
    Public Property CategoryID As Integer = Nothing
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Rank As Integer
    Public Property Found As Boolean = False
    Public Property Children As New List(Of CategoryStructure)
End Class

Public Class CampaignStructure
    Public Property CampaignID As String = Nothing
    Public Property Categories As List(Of CategoryStructure)
End Class

Public Module ControlExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function FindRecursive(cs As List(Of CategoryStructure), predicate As Func(Of CategoryStructure, Boolean), depthLimit As Integer) As List(Of CategoryStructure)
        If cs Is Nothing OrElse cs.Count = 0 Then
            Return New List(Of CategoryStructure)()
        End If

        If depthLimit = 0 Then
            Return cs.OfType(Of CategoryStructure)().Where(predicate).ToList()
        Else
            '**ERROR IS THROWN HERE**
            Return cs.OfType(Of CategoryStructure)().Where(predicate).ToList().Union(cs.Cast(Of CategoryStructure).Select(Of List(Of CategoryStructure))(Function(c) c.Children.FindRecursive(predicate, depthLimit - 1)).ToList())
        End If
    End Function

End Module

End Namespace
```

However I'm having casting problems when I'm unioning the recursive result with the current list at the point in the code marked. I can see why that's happening, just have no idea how to resolve it. Please do not send me C# examples as there is no 'yield' alternative in VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because both sides of `UNION` have different signatures.

```
cs.OfType(Of CategoryStructure)().Where(predicate).ToList()
```

This returns `List(Of CategoryStructure)`.

```
cs.Cast(Of CategoryStructure).Select(Of List(Of CategoryStructure))(Function(c) c.Children.FindRecursive(predicate, depthLimit - 1)).ToList()
```

This one returns `List(Of List(Of CategoryStructure))`

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Return cs.OfType(Of CategoryStructure)().Where(predicate).Union(cs.Cast(Of CategoryStructure).SelectMany(Function(c) c.Children.FindRecursive(predicate, depthLimit - 1))).ToList()
```

`SelectMany` returns flattened collection typed as `IEnumerable(Of CategoryStructure)`.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, was trying various things on this and had strayed away from SelectMany after a few variations which weren't quite right - this was my downfall! Just couldn't get my head around it enough to fully understand what was going on.